# How can i repeat an animation set with css, at every click using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I created a rotation animation in css that takes 1s and has 'forwards' set with a class .comet .  How can i have that animation start at every click on an exterior element?

```
 #carousel #big_bubble #cometa.rotation{animation:rotation 1s forwards; -moz-animation:rotation 1.5s forwards; -webkit-animation:rotation 1s forwards; -o-animation:rotation forwards 1s; }
    @-moz-keyframes rotation{
        from{transform:rotate(0deg);}
        to{transform:rotate(-360deg);}
 @-webkit-keyframes rotation{
        from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
        to{-webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);}
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a FIDDLE link ?

Comment: i provided the animation on CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(function() {// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
    $( ".trigger" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass( "animation" ).one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", function(){
            $(this).removeClass( "animation" );
        });
    });
});
```

Resources:

1. [How to Capture CSS3 Animation Events in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/)
2. [jQuery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand you right. Anyway:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var el = $('#cometa').addClass('rotation');
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.removeClass('rotation');
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPv3B/

Comment: We shared the aproximate same answer on aproximate same time. It works. I only had to add extra time for removing class - the animation didn't finished very smooth with only 1000ms. Thx for your contribution anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

On every click of the a element you add the css class to the element .
check this code .

if `.comet` is your css animation class then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#everybutton_element_id').click(function (e) {
            $(this).addClass('comet');
            $(this).delay(2000).removeClass('comet');
     });
});
```

repeat the same code for any no of elements on which you want to implement it .

Comment: but it adds the class and it stays there. at the second click the animation it doesn't take place.

Comment: do you have many buttons or just one button . on which you want to fire this css class .

Comment: i have edited my code above . use it now it will work fine . as you want it to work .

Comment: i provided the tab yesterday

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '#next', function() {
     $("#cometa").addClass("rotation");
     setTimeout(function () {
    $("#cometa").removeClass('rotation');
}, 1500);
});
```

This works for my problem. I remove that class after animation-time is finished.